# shape of plot distorts when higher values are used

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am working on a plot using matplotlib in python. It works fine when I use smaller values as shown below:
[image]

I need to use the output of the following function to plot the values of x-axis

```
def xticks1():
base=100
for i in range(8):
    base=base*10
    a.append(base)
return a
```

When I use the value of `a`, it distorts the plot as below:
[image: distorted plot]
Here is my complete code

```
    import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[]
sample=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def xticks1():
    base=100
    for i in range(8):
        base=base*10
        a.append(base)
    return a
    
xticks1()

y_points = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.95,0.98,1]
plt.plot( a, y_points,  marker="*",label="data mining")


plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('load')
plt.ylabel('FCT(ms)')

print (a)
plt.xticks(a,rotation=70)

plt.yticks(y_points)
plt.title("title 1")    import sys
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

a=[]
sample=[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]

def xticks1():
    base=100
    for i in range(8):
        base=base*10
        a.append(base)
    return a
    
xticks1()

y_points = [0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,0.95,0.98,1]
plt.plot( a, y_points,  marker="*",label="data mining")


plt.legend(loc="upper left")
plt.grid(True)
plt.xlabel('load')
plt.ylabel('FCT(ms)')

print (a)
plt.xticks(a,rotation=70)

plt.yticks(y_points)
plt.title("title 1")
plt.show() 

plt.show()
```

I am not getting any reason behind the distortion of the graph. Why it distorts after just increasing the x-axis values? I am totally new to `matplotlib` that's why I am not getting the issue. Any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

**Problem**
The values on X-Axis are not appearing as expected. These are too much zoom out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't really see what the problem is, are you trying to just have a linear or logarithmic X-axis values? Is that where it goes wrong?

if linear, you can just omit giving X values and it will automatically start from 0 to length of y_points.
If logarithmic, you can add `plt.set_xscale('log')`

If that's not your question, please clarify

Comment: it causes the issues while setting the values for x

Comment: Glad to hear! For more info visit https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.xscale.html